# Sort a List of objects by a certain argument

Tags: java, sorting

I Have and ArrayList of objects that have several arguments.
I need to make a method that sorts the list by a certain argument.
My class is:

```
public class VehicleLoaded {

private int vlrefid;
private int vehicleRefId;
private int load_time;
...

public ELPEVehicleLoaded(){}
}
```

I need to sort the ArrayList that contains such objects by its load times (in ascending order).
Here is my Comparator:

```
public static Comparator<ELPEVehicleLoaded> RouteLoadingTime = new Comparator<ELPEVehicleLoaded>() 
{
    public int compare(ELPEVehicleLoaded vl1, ELPEVehicleLoaded vl2) {

    int vl1_load_time=vl1.getLoadTime();

    int vl2_load_time=vl2.getLoadTime();
    /*For ascending order*/
    return vl1_load_time-vl2_load_time;
}};
```

Hence I created a static method to sort:

```
public static void sortListByLoadTime (ArrayList<VehicleLoaded> VLs){
Collections.sort(VLs, new MyComparator());
}
```

Sorry if this question has been brought up again, I've been searching but couldn't find an answer that suits me.
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: shouldn't you pass in RouteLoadingTime rather than new MyComparator()?

Comment: `Collections.sort(a, Comparator.comparing(ELPEVehicleLoaded::getLoadTime));`

Comment: Looks like you've got the right idea.  So what's the difficulty?

Comment: Wait, so if I have 
  Collections.sort(VLs, vl.RouteLoadingTime);
with vl being an object for access to VehicleLoaded, will work?

Comment: @KevinAnderson I'm really really confused. You know, like the times that the answer might be in front of you, but can't see it.

Comment: No, you were perfectly correct with `Collections.sort(VLs, new MyComparator());`.  Did it not work correctly when you ran it?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MyObj> a = Arrays.asList(new MyObj(5), new MyObj(4),new MyObj(3),new MyObj(2), new MyObj(1));

        Collections.sort(a, Comparator.comparingInt(MyObj::getLoadTime));

        System.out.println(a);
    }
}

class MyObj {
    int loadTime;

    public MyObj(int loadTime) {
        this.loadTime = loadTime;
    }

    public int getLoadTime() {
        return loadTime;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + loadTime;
    }
}
```

The output of this will be:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

So in your case all you need to add to your `sortListByLoadTime` method is:

`Collections.sort(VLs, Comparator.comparingInt(ELPEVehicleLoaded::getLoadTime));`

and as we are talking about an `ArrayList` you should use its sort method rather than Collections::sort. In the example I gave it will be like :

`Collections.sort(VLs, Comparator.comparingInt(ELPEVehicleLoaded::getLoadTime));`

->
 `VLs.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(ELPEVehicleLoaded::getLoadTime));`

Comment: Or since Java 8 just `a.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(MyObj::getLoadTime));`

Comment: I did ... but what did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `comparator` inside your function `sortListByLoadTime`  as shown below:

```
VLs.sort((o1,o2) -> o1.getLoadTime() - o2.getLoadTime());
```

Or you can use `Collections utility` as shown below:

```
Collections.sort(VLs, ( o1,  o2) -> {
      return o1.getLoadTime() - o2.getLoadTime();
});
```

The `lambda expression` can be replaced by `method reference` as shown below:

```
Collections.sort(VLs, Comparator.comparing(VehicleLoaded::getLoadTime));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Java 8 way:

```
VLs.stream()
    .sorted((v1,v2)-> {
        if(v1.getLoadTime()<v2.getLoadTime()) {
            return -1;
        }
        if(v1.getLoadTime()>v2.getLoadTime()) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That's nice and understandable!

Comment: @DimitrisBoukosis you do realize that this code will not sort the elements in VLs, right? So you will have to either do `VLs = VLs.stream().sorted(lambda).collect(new ArrayList(...))` or  you will have to refer to ArrayList::sort directly as : `VLs.sort(lambda)` rather than  ArrayList::stream. Also the quoted lambda is the equivalent of Comparator::comparingInt and any modern IDE will highlight its body and suggest using the common one. This is answer is the misused version(probably change it a bit for free RPs) of the @Yug Singh answer...